# CSS Styling is applied to the submenu border on live website but why it is not working

Tags: css, wordpress, navbar, submenu

CSS border is applied to the nav sub menu but it's working on localhost but not working on the live WordPress site tangentconsulting.ca. Here is the code.

```
@media all and (min-width: 1025px) {

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu {
    position: fixed!important;
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: normal;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 96.25vw!important;
    left: 1.25vw!important;
    top: unset;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-width: 1px!important;
    border-color: black!important;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #ffffff,
        #ffffff 10px,
        #fdfdfd 10px,
        #fdfdfd 20px
    );
}

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu li.menu-item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis: 16.6%;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0!important;
/*  border-right: 1px solid #aaaaaa!important; */
    position: relative;
    padding-left: .8em;
}

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right-width: 0!important;
}

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu li.menu-item a {
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
}

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu li.menu-item a:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border: solid .3em black;
    border-radius: .3em;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    position: static!important;
}

.tc-mega-menu li:nth-child(2) ul.sub-menu li.menu-item:hover a:before{
    border-color: #D35C48;
}
    
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px){
    
    .tc-mega-menu  nav {
        width: 900%!important;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
}
```

I tried to check from inspect and it's applied but I'm not able to see it on website. It should be like this.
[Local host showing the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yewyh.png)

But after pushig the same code to the live, it looks like this.
[live site tangentconsulting.ca's nav submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC3Ca.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: The `border-style` is `none`, so see to it that you explicitly set that as well.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much for mentioning the mistake. It works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.